# stacking images vertically with javascript when screen size is less than 500px

Tags: javascript

I am trying to stack images two on top of two when the screen size is less than 500px (for example) using javascript.  Each of these images can have an `href` link but won't always.

This is some example html when greater than 500px:

```
<div id="topbanners1-4-a" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">
  <img id="front-end-top" src="https://www.mysite.co.uk/secure/images/banners/0.png" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
  <img id="front-end-top" src="https://www.mysite.co.uk/secure/images/banners/2.jpg" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
  <a href="https://www.mysite.co.uk/Silentnight-Divan-Beds-and-Mattresses-c99">
    <img id="front-end-top" src="https://www.mysite.co.uk/secure/images/banners/4.jpg" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
  </a>
  <img id="front-end-top" src="https://www.mysite.co.uk/secure/images/banners/3.jpg" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
</div>
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to do this.  Ultimately I'd like to have something like this when the screen size is less than 500px:

```
<div id="topbanners1-4-a" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">
  <div id="one">      
    <img id="front-end-top" src="https://www.mysite.co.uk/secure/images/banners/0.png" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
    <img id="front-end-top" src="https://www.mysite.co.uk/secure/images/banners/2.jpg" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
 </div><div id="two">
  <a href="https://www.mysite.co.uk/Silentnight-Divan-Beds-and-Mattresses-c99">
    <img id="front-end-top" src="https://www.mysite.co.uk/secure/images/banners/4.jpg" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
  </a>
  <img id="front-end-top" src="https://www.mysite.co.uk/secure/images/banners/3.jpg" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example so far, although images are missing:
http://plnkr.co/edit/obLQorTFEsI467AHJspm?p=preview

Looking for any help or advice that will help me achieve this.

Comment: Why do you use JavaScript for it and not a CSS media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript and its [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) and alter inline styles, though it is recommended to use classes and external CSS rules.

Stack snippet

```js
function watchMedia(wM) {
    if (wM.matches) { // If media query matches
        document.querySelector('#topbanners1-4-a').style.whiteSpace = "normal";
        var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('#topbanners1-4-a img');
        for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
          imgs[i].style.width = "calc(50% - 10px)";
          imgs[i].style.marginBottom = "10px";
          if (i % 2 == 1)
            imgs[i].style.marginLeft = "10px";
        }
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#topbanners1-4-a').style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
        var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('#topbanners1-4-a img');
        for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
          imgs[i].style.width = "25%";
          imgs[i].style.marginBottom = "0";
          if (i % 2 == 1)
            imgs[i].style.marginLeft = "0";
        }
    }
}

var wM = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")

watchMedia(wM)             // Call once at page load
wM.addListener(watchMedia) // Listen for state changes
```

```html
<div id="topbanners1-4-a" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">
  <img id="front-end-top" src="http://placehold.it/300/f00" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
  <img id="front-end-top" src="http://placehold.it/300/0f0" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
  <a href="https://www.mysite.co.uk/Silentnight-Divan-Beds-and-Mattresses-c99">
    <img id="front-end-top" src="http://placehold.it/300/00f" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
  </a>
  <img id="front-end-top" src="http://placehold.it/300/f0f" style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
</div>
```

Or [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and external CSS rules

```css
#topbanners1-4-a {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#topbanners1-4-a img {
  width: calc(25% - 5px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #topbanners1-4-a {
    white-space: normal;
  }
  #topbanners1-4-a img {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #topbanners1-4-a > *:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="topbanners1-4-a">
  <img id="front-end-top" src="http://placehold.it/300/f00" alt="" />
  <img id="front-end-top" src="http://placehold.it/300/0f0" alt="" />
  <a href="https://www.mysite.co.uk/Silentnight-Divan-Beds-and-Mattresses-c99">
    <img id="front-end-top" src="http://placehold.it/300/00f" alt="" />
  </a>
  <img id="front-end-top" src="http://placehold.it/300/f0f" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, thank you very much, that's really helped me out! :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing it with CSS media queries?

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {

    #topbanners1-4-a img {
        width: 50%;
    }

}
```